# Error for insert PersianDate on datagrid :Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state

Tags: c#, wpf, get, persian-calendar

In WPF project I have got a `DataGrid` name `DG` which is bind to Query in SQL
in C# side I try to Convert `string MiladiDate` to PersianDate. But the error that is shown as title said:

> Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state

Here is the code where I change get/ set:

```
namespace DataModelLayer
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Globalization;

    public partial class Vw_DD_MM
    {
        public int MMID { get; set; }

        public string MiladiDate
        {
            get
            {
                DateTime englishDate = DateTime.Parse(MiladiDate);
                PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
                return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", pc.GetYear(englishDate), pc.GetMonth(englishDate).ToString("00"), pc.GetDayOfMonth(englishDate).ToString("00"));
            }
            set { }
        }
    }
}
```

Please see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUtXQ.png) of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a recursion loop in gette body. You see, `MiladiDate` call itself in `DateTime.Parse(MiladiDate)`. Try out something like this:

```
public partial class Vw_DD_MM
{
    public int MMID { get; set; }

    public string MiladiDate { get; set; }

    public string PersianDate
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime englishDate = DateTime.Parse(MiladiDate);
            PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
            return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", pc.GetYear(englishDate), pc.GetMonth(englishDate).ToString("00"), pc.GetDayOfMonth(englishDate).ToString("00"));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.